# Go MUX controller returns 404

Tags: go, mux

I must be missing something really obvious, but I've created a MUX routed controller and the server returns 404.  Running the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/hi", SayHi)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func SayHi(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hi")
}
```

Visit : http://localhost:8080/hi  and I get a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pass **router** variable as second parameter to `http.ListenAndServe` instead of **nil**

Comment: Arg - knew it had to be something simple. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass **router** variable as second parameter to [http.ListenAndServe()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) instead of **nil**